# How to transform multiple similar outputs into a single output array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two issues that I desperately need help with, so I'm posting here.

I know this may sound like a much-asked question at first, but I didn't find anything like it in my research.

I'm trying to obtain an entire row of results, using this code:

```
mu = [0 0];
sigma = [1 0.3; 0.3 1];

    for r1 = 1:7;
        r2 = 1;

        xu = [r1+1, r2+1];
        xl = [r1, r2];

        p1 = mvncdf(xl,xu,mu,sigma)
    end
```

What I am trying to say is that, for every value that r1 takes (between 1 and 7), r2 will assume the value 1, and I want to generate the values for those 7 combinations. When I run the scripts, I get excatly the values that I want, but in this form:

```
p1 =

    0.0301


p1 =

    0.0062


p1 =

   4.5904e-04


p1 =

   1.2186e-05


p1 =

   1.1389e-07


p1 =

   3.7054e-10


p1 =

   4.1622e-13
```

After that, when I go to my workspace, I have a variable there named p1, but is only equal to the last value generated - in this case, 4.1622e-13. Is it possible to make this generate an array with all the 7 numbers instead?

My second question is related to this one. As you saw, I use r1 ranging from 1 to 7, and r2 takes the value of 1. Truth is, I want to assess all combinations of them, with r2 also ranging from 1 to 7, but I'm doing it manually, with 7 other similar pieces of code, each one for a value of r2. Is it possible to combine everything and code it in a way that it generates a matrix of values based on all the combinations? I understand that might be more difficult, and I am more concerned with the first question.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, you want to create a vector of `p1` values, so just modify your code like this:

```
p1(r1) = mvncdf(xl,xu,mu,sigma)
```

which when `r1=1`, the first time you loop, will put the result into the first element of `p1` and so on.

For the second part of your question, you can nest another `for` loop, as follows:

```
for r1 = 1:7;
    for r2 = 1:7;
        xu = [r1+1, r2+1];
        xl = [r1, r2];

        p1(r1,r2) = mvncdf(xl,xu,mu,sigma)
    end
end
```

and now you will have a matrix `p1` where, for example, the entry in the (4,6) position corresponds to `r1=4` and `r2=6`.

It is possible to compress this,

```
r1=1:7;
r2=1:7;
[R1,R2]=meshgrid(r1,r2);
p1=arrayfun(@(r1,r2) mvncdf([r1 r2],[r1+1 r2+1],mu,sigma),R1,R2)
```

but there is no real need to do so.

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark this answer as accepted so that others know that this problem is resolved.